# SQL Server Windows authentication error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Server 2016 on Windows Server 2012.

Also I am using SQL Server in a workgroup.

What I did is

- installed AD DC (SQL server was installed before i install AD DC)
- Removed AD DC to go back to workgroup and get local administrator user

After I did this, I cannot login to SQL Server using Windows Auth anymore

When I try to login with Windows authentication, I got this error

> Login failed for user 'domain\username'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

and I checked error log for the error state, the error state was 5.

But when I connect using `sa` user and checked login folder in Security folder, I see the correct user with the same name as my local user name. See the screenshot below

My local admin username is `WIN-2NEKEGJF11Q\Administrator`

Please, help me

-see the red line

[image]

Comment: Remove and recreate that user.

Comment: If i remove and recreate that user, will it effect to the tool that using this user linked to database? if it dose, is there other way to recover this user?

Comment: Create a temp user with admin privilege and first play with him (her). In the case of success continue with your real admin.

Comment: I created temp user with admin privilege and it works well. but when i tried with real admin it doesn't work still saying 18456 error

Comment: Did you really get print screen with your phone?

Comment: did you try to make this user as "db owner?"

Comment: I tried to set Administrator user as db_owner but nothing change

Comment: I can login with windows authentication by using single-user mod  to this Administrator account but idk what should i do to recover this account

Comment: @ibubi Server box is not connected to internet so i had to take picture with my phone lol